# What is the mandala of the ground?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, tantra, mandala

When you first learn about mandalas, you learn about [sand paintings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandala):

[image]

But in the Guhyagarbha tantra, outlined in [Luminous Essence: A Guide to the Guhyagarbha Tantra](https://wisdomcompassion.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Luminous-Essence-A-Guide-to-the-Guhyagarbha-Tantra.pdf), it is said:

> The *subject matter* of this tantra is the **maṇḍala of the ground**, the ultimate natural state of all phenomena, which is primordially of an enlightened
> nature within great purity and equality. Moreover, the tantra also shows the
> path, the various means that allow one to actualize this ground either directly
> or indirectly. Finally, the tantra reveals the maṇḍala of the fruition—perfect,
> total purity. In short, the tantra teaches the profound realization of mantra,
> as subsumed within ground, path, and fruition.

Where can I find more information on this deeper meaning of mandala. What is the mandala of the ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context "mandala" means "a living situation, with you in the center" or "a configuration of elements as seen from the inside".

So "mandala of the ground" means to see things from the perspective that takes "the ground" as one's living reality ("the ground" defined in the text as "the ultimate natural state of all phenomena, which is primordially of an enlightened nature within great purity and equality").

Similarly "mandala of fruition" is to see things from the perspective of Enlightenment (which is "perfect, total purity" attained when you "actualize this ground").

In other words, the text talks about shifting your perspective, the way you see and construct your reality.